# Copying the same value after splitting the one cell

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab. Can anyone suggest me how to do the below mentioned task in matlab?

My data is like this

```
Band         Operators      Class
1A-5A        A, S, B, C       A1
```

I want to convert it to this kind of table

```
Band         Operators        Class 
1A-5A            A              A1
1A-5A            S              A1
1A-5A            B              A1
1A-5A            C              A1
```

Thank you very much!!

Dhruv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data={'1A-5A',{'A','S','B','C'},'A1'};
a=arrayfun(@(i) [data{1},data{2}(i),data{3}],1:length(data{2}),'Unif',false);
cell2table(a','VariableNames',{'mytable'})

    mytable        
______________________

'1A-5A'    'A'    'A1'
'1A-5A'    'S'    'A1'
'1A-5A'    'B'    'A1'
'1A-5A'    'C'    'A1'
```

You can look at table command to change headings as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much Nasser for help.